# High performance recursive functions in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I am learning C++ and I was toying with linked lists.

Consider the following extremely simple implementation:

```cpp
static std::size_t n_constructors {0};


template <typename T>
class list {
public:
    list(T n) : item{n} { n_constructors++; }
    list(T n, list* l) : item{n}, next {l} { n_constructors++; }
    list(const list&);
    ~list() { delete next; }
    void insert(T n);
    void print() const;
    list reverse() const;
    list reverse_iter() const;
private:
    T item;
    list* next {nullptr};
};


template <typename T>
list<T>::list(const list& src)
    :
    item {src.item}
{
    n_constructors++;
    if (src.next) {
        next = new list {*src.next};
    }
}


template <typename T>
void list<T>::insert(T n) {
    if (next == nullptr)
        next = new list {n};
    else
        next->insert(n);
}


template <typename T>
void list<T>::print() const {
    std::cout << item << " ";
    if (next)
        next->print();
    else
        std::cout << std::endl;
}


template <typename T>
list<T> list<T>::reverse() const {
    if (next) {
        auto s = next->reverse();
        s.insert(item);
        return s;
    } else {
        return list {item};
    }
}


template <typename T>
list<T> list<T>::reverse_iter() const {
    auto sptr = new list<T> {item};
    auto prev = next;
    auto link = next;
    while (link) {
        auto tmp = new list<T>(link->item, sptr);
        link = link->next;
        prev = link;
        sptr = tmp;
    }
    return *sptr;
}
```

As you can see, I wrote two reverse functions: an iterative one and a recursive one.
To test them out, I tried this:

```cpp
int main() {
    list<int> s{1};
    for (int i = 2; i < 10000; ++i)
        s.insert(i);
    std::cout << "initial constructor\n";
    std::cout << "called " << n_constructors << " constructors.\n";
    auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto s2 = s.reverse_iter();
    auto t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "iterative reverse\n";
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t - t0).count() <<" ms\n";
    std::cout << "called " << n_constructors << " constructors.\n";
    t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto s3 = s.reverse();
    t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "recursive reverse\n";
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t - t0).count() <<" ms\n";
    std::cout << "called " << n_constructors << " constructors.\n";
}
```

here's a typical result of my benchmark (compiled with g++ 9.3.0, optimiser turned on with `-O2`):

```
initial constructor
called 9999 constructors.
iterative reverse
0 ms
called 29997 constructors.
recursive reverse
1692 ms
called 50034995 constructors.
```

The difference in performance is staggering.
I guess that the problem with the recursive version is the much larger number of allocations, so I implement a move constructor:

```cpp
template <typename T>
list<T>::list(list&& src)
    :
    item {src.item},
    next {src.next}
{
    n_constructors++;
    src.next = nullptr;
    src.item = 0;
}
```

This is the result:

```
initial constructor
called 9999 constructors.
iterative reverse
0 ms
called 29997 constructors.
recursive reverse
90 ms
called 49994 constructors.
```

Very good, now at least the recursive function does just as many allocations as the iterative function.
The performance difference is however still large.
I try again with 100 000 elements:

```
initial constructor
called 99999 constructors.
iterative reverse
7 ms
called 299997 constructors.
recursive reverse
9458 ms
called 499994 constructors.
```

In my opinion the recursive reverse is much more readable and elegant than the iterative one.

Why is the recursive version so much slower?
Is there something I can do to make it faster?

## Edit

I add the plots with the empirical asymptotic order of growth for the two algorithms, as recommended by Will Ness in the comments.

[image: empirical order of growth on an intel i7-6700HQ]

Comment: It seems you're asking a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215420/are-loops-really-faster-than-recursion).

Comment: `reverse_iter` is linear, `reverse` is quadratic (since it calls `insert` which is itself linear). You spend time traversing links, not calling constructors.

Comment: @JaMiT if there is no way to make recursion faster than looping, I would be happy just to know why recursion is so much slower (3 orders of magnitude!) despite doing as many allocations as the iterative version.

Comment: It's not about recursion per se. It's about having to traverse the half-built list every time to insert the node at the end. The way `reverse` works is, it traverses the list to the end, and makes a copy of the last node. Then it inserts the copy of the next-to-last node into this one-element list. Then it inserts a copy of the previous note into this two-element list, traversing it to the end. And so on. For every node, it ends up traversing the partially-built reverse list all the way from start to end. In contrast, `reverse_iter` does all the work in a single pass.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik makes sense, thanks. I think I could make the recursive algorithm linear again just by keeping a pointer to the last element of the list, does it sound right?

Comment: You could, yes. Though I suspect at that point it won't be much simpler than `reverse_iter` (By the way, `prev` is not used for anything in `reverse_iter`; you can drop it and shave two lines of code). Also, make sure to compile with all optimizations enabled for benchmarking; most recursion in your code is tail recursion, the compiler should be able to covert it to iteration automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not only testing here between recursion and iteration, but between two algorithms that have a different order of growth.

Your `reverse` has the complexity T(n) = T(n - 1) + O(n), and so is quadratic in the number of links. Your `reverse_iter` has only linear complexity. The comparison is unfair, therefore.

Comment: Did you mean T(n) = T(n - 1) + O(n)?

Comment: @J.D. that would make it quadratic, n*n. also, performance comparisons at *one* size point are largely meaningless. see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth). the meaningful one is the log-log plot of time vs problem size, with at least two size points.

Comment: @WillNess point taken, thanks. I think the answer by Ami Tavory wanted indeed to point out that `reverse` is quadratic, so it cannot be T(n) = T(n - 1) + O(1) which is linear in n.

Comment: @J.D. ah, right. I thought it referred to the other one. :) btw, the meaningful comparison is the log-log plot of time vs problem size, with at least two size points. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992904/enumerate-factors-of-a-number-directly-in-ascending-order-without-sorting) for an excellent example. that's for a power law growth; for exponential it's the log-plot of course.

Comment: @WillNess It's a very meaningful plot and I will try to make a similar plot for my code (tomorrow I hope). The log log plot should make it possible to compare the two algorithms despite the vast difference in performance. I see the cry for empirical orders of growth in your profile page, are you worried that asymptotic order of growth might be too asymptotic?

Comment: @J.D. all I'm saying is, use it. I don't draw whole plots, myself, just do some 2-3-4 measurements at 2x the size (or 10x, whatever), usually it's enough.

Comment: @WillNess I finally found the time to add the plots in my original post. It was also quite fun to generate the data---I hope my CPU was not throttled down too much as I did this benchmark on a laptop and I could distinctively feel it heat up.